# Wrap text in PyDev editor

Tags: python, pydev, usability

Is it possible to set text wrapping in PyDev?

For Python such feature is especially important because you cant freely use newline characters.

Comment: `pprint.pprint` has linewrapping capabilites. Also what do you mean `you can't freely use newline characters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python syntax depends on indentation. So automatic text wrapping spoils the syntax.
But you can tell Python to continue  a statement on the next line. See the style guide under Maximum Line Length : : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thank you! Didnt know about wrapping inside brackets. Also noticed, that in "source" menu in PyDev exists a "wrap paragraph" function - but it wraps not only line within brackets, but whole code block! Wondering - how it can be useful while editing Python code

Comment: @Gill Bates: I cannot find this menu in Eclipse PyDev

Comment: Thanks, I must be blind. I tried to use this function. But with my tryal it results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

In PyDev, the Source/Wrap paragraph menu (Ctrl+2, w) wraps the current line automatically. You should of course check if the output is what you expected.